# How to extract data from a .sql file and use it in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a .sql file which contains information about cities. It's already executed and has all the data. It has fields like id, city_name, state and country. For an example, a tuple in the file looks like this:

```
257, 'Tuscaloosa ', 'Alabama ', 'United States'
```

Now, I have a string. For an example :

```
I live in Chicago.
```

Now I have to find if the string contains any of the cities mentioned in the .sql file. If any such city of the .sql file is present in the string, the name of the city, state and country are to be stored in separate variables. How to do that in Python in effective way?

Comment: Query the database accordingly? You're using SQLite?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you stuck at?

Comment: @moenad and Yilun : I thought to solve it by considering the .sql file just like a .txt file. for each line in the file, after the first single quote the name of a city starts and spans till the next quote. like: 'Tuscaloosa' . Now, i'll search for this word in the string. If match occurs, store the value in vars or go to the next line. - this is my algo. Is it possible to do this in this way? If it is, I can't write the correct code in Python.

Comment: If you have a SQL file put it in a database and use it that way. If you want a neutral data format that Python can deal with, CSV or JSON works better than SQL.